# How can I use my table for Views 3 sort criteria?

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to create a special sort criterium.
I have a table with 2 cols: *nid*, and *count*.

How can I use this table to sort the view by count?

Answer (score 1):

You can let Views know about your data using [hook_views_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data).

The function documentation itself contains all the information you need to use the data for sorting and other Views functions, so I'm not repeating them here.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a module and implement `hook_views_query_alter()`

Check [this](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!docs!views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) for details.